# Windows store app certification failed - New user sign up for services missing

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-store

- Our windows store application is especially for our customers.
- It requires user credential to login.
- It doesn't have any sign up page.
- New users cannot access our application(They should be our customer.)
- For new users, Admin will create an account and share them to the
  user.
- At the first time, user is requested to change password.

This is how our customer access our application

We submitted our free business app to the windows store.

But it is rejected with the reason saying "*Apps that require users to sign in must either specify upfront in app description the type of access user must have and how to get it or **provide a mechanism for new users to sign up for services from within the app**. At a minimum this could be a link in the app to the website where the user can create a new account and sign up for services. Your app did not appear to provide this information to the user.*"

We do not have such a page. How can we proceed for resubmission?

Whether we need to provide description like "Our application can be accessible to our customers only"

or

provide support email address and saying like "Contact our support team/admin to create new account"

or

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply show a description which tells user that this app is only for registered customers. For more details you can write us to your email id or can fully describe the log in process there on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

The description says it all. Include exactly what you have said in the application's description update. In addition include this information on the main page of your application for extra safety.

Note how DropBox has done it. When you install the app your very first screen has the login boxes and a link to "or Create an Account" which then brings you to a webpage to create the account.

You could link this to a page on your site that allows a user to contact your org for an account or register for one to then be approved, etc